# How should I write this regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the string.

```
st = "12345 hai how  r u @3456? Awer12345 7890"
re.findall('([0-9]+)',st)
```

It should not come like :

```
['12345', '3456', '12345', '7890']
```

I should get

```
['12345','7890']
```

I should only take the numeric values

and

It should not contain any other chars like alphabets,special chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [21]: re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)(\d+)(?=$|\s)', st)
Out[21]: ['12345', '7890']
```

Here,

- `(?:^|\s)` is a non-capture group that matches the start of the string, or a space.
- `(\d+)` is a capture group that matches one or more digits.
- `(?=$|\s)` is lookahead assertion that matches the end of the string, or a space, *without consuming it*.

Comment: same problem as with @Ademiban's solution: This will not find '456' in '123 456' because the inner space is "consumed" by the first match.

Comment: @JanPöschko: Good catch, thanks. Fixed (by converting the final group into a lookahead assertion).

Comment: @JanPöschko Thanks. It is not working for this     "12345 hai how  r u @3456? Awer12345 7890123ER%345 234 456 789"

Comment: @saravana: The updated version gives `['12345', '234', '456', '789']`. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: @aix This result is expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

No need to use a regular expression:

```
[i for i in st.split(" ") if i.isdigit()]
```

Which I think is much more readable than using a regex

Answer (score 3):

Corey's solution is really the right way to go here, but since the question did ask for regex, here is a regex solution that I think is simpler than the others:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', st)
```

And an explanation:

```
(?<!\S)   # Fail if the previous character (if one exists) isn't whitespace
\d+       # Match one or more digits
(?!\S)    # Fail if the next character (if one exists) isn't whitespace
```

Some examples:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', '12345 hai how  r u @3456? Awer12345 7890')
['12345', '7890']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', '12345 hai how r u @3456? Awer12345 7890123ER%345 234 456 789')
['12345', '234', '456', '789']
```

Answer (score 2):

use this: `(^|\s)[0-9]+(\s|$)` pattern. `(^|\s)` means that your number must be at the start of the string or there must be a whitespace character before the number. And `(\s|$)` means that there must be a whitespace after number or the number is at the end of the string.
As said Jan Pöschko, 456 won't be found in 123 456. If your "bad" parts (@, Awer) are always prefixes, you can use this `(^|\s)[0-9]+` pattern and everything will be OK. It will match all numbers, which have only whitespaces before or are at the start of the string. Hope this helped...

Comment: This will not find '456' in '123 456' because the inner space is "consumed" by the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression finds all sequences of digits, regardless of what surrounds them. You need to include a specification of what comes before and after the sequence to get the behavior you want:

```
re.findall(r"[\D\b](\d+)[\D\b]", st)
```

will do what you want. In English, it says "match all sequences of one or more digits that are surrounded by a non-digit character.or a word boundary"

Comment: This returns ['3456', '12345'] when he wants ['12345','7890'].  I'm ever more convinced of my view that regexes are more trouble than they're worth unless they're trivial.